# Inherit a C struct and pass object pointer to c function - it is safe?

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

As I know, C++ does not have it's own classes for time calculation, so we can use the  functionality for the C library.

So, I decided to make a C++ wrapper class, which works with struct timespec and calls functions, that work with struct timespec. As structs and classes are almost the same in C++, a class can inherit a struct. So, i can inherit struct timespec like this:

```
class Time: timespec {
  public:
    Time();
    Time(int mseconds);

    Time operator+(Time& t1);
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Time &t);
};
```

Now the question: 
In C we do this to get the current monotonic time:

```
struct timespec ts;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,&ts);
```

And in my C++ class I want the constructor to initialize the class with the current time.

```
Time::Time()
{
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC,this);
}
```

using the this pointer like struct timespec pointer.

It compiles OK, but...

Is this safe? Is it guaranteed, that it should work?

When inheriting a class, a pointer to derived class is compatible with pointer to base class. But is that pointer compatible with a pointer to C struct, passed to C function?

Comment: C++ 11 does have its own classes for time calculations: [Date and time utilities](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono)

Comment: The problem with that will come if you add virtual methods or other data members. As long as you don't do any of that it should be safe.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg What kind of problems? The inheritance is private, therefore there shouldn't be problems. BTW very interesting idea.

Comment: @BЈовић: The object's memory layout wouldn't be a plain C struct (since most compilers add a vptr to the struct) which a C API might count on, there by landing in UB land.

Comment: @legends2k If you add virtual methods (and introduce virtual tables, but that is implementation defined behavior), shouldn't standard compliant compiler still do the right thing, and set the proper offsets? After all, the standard talks about memory alignment.

Comment: @BЈовић Well, which standard are we talking about? C++ or C's? In C there's no notion of objects and it isn't uncommon for C APIs allocating 1 byte more than an array or struct requires to do book keeping etc

Comment: @legends2k c++ of course. In c such things do not happen ;)

Comment: @BЈовић: But the OP wants to pass his C++ object as a C struct to C functions :)

Comment: @legends2k Then you are talking about implementation defined behavior, since c++ standard doesn't mention virtual table. It is up to the chosen compiler to make it work properly. BTW the question doesn't mention virtual keyword anywhere

Answer (score 3):

Your particular example of passing `this` from a constructor, is safe, because the formal argument type of `clock_gettime` is `const struct timespec *` (which converts the pointer, adjusting for any possible offset).

The standard places some restrictions on passing `this` from a constructor. Essentially it concerns calls back on the object before construction has finished. But you're not doing that.

But rather than worry about it, why not just use a data member instead of inheritance?

---

By the way, note that C++ now, as of C++11, has the `<chrono>` header, with higher level time utilities.

Comment: Is it really safe?  Are the member fields of the subclass guaranteed to be aligned in the same places that they are in the superclass (or super-nonclass)?  I wouldn't trust that to be immune to compiler- and architecture-specific factors.  As you say, better to use a data member.

Comment: @jez: yes, it's safe, and no, the subclass can e.g. introduce a vtable pointer at the start, *but* the conversion of the pointer to the formal argument type takes care of any offset issue.